# How to get proper message with no additional changes when decoding using AES?

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I'm trying to use AES encryption using pyaes for an MQTT application. During the decoding I get my input with b'Message' instead of just the message. How do I ensure the message just prints out ? Trim and transalte function do not work

```
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import os
import pyaes
import sys

# This is the Subscriber

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
  print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
  client.subscribe("topic/test")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    #keys = os.urandom(16)
    #iv   = os.urandom(16)

    keys = //Random Keys
    iv   = //Random IV Key
    bart = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationOFB(keys,iv=iv)

    decrypted = bart.decrypt(msg.payload)
    #print(msg.payload,"\n")
    print("Message is : ",decrypted,"\n")
    client.disconnect()

broker      = "192.168.1.104"
port        = 1883
keepalive   = 60

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect(broker,port,keepalive)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.loop_forever()
```

The Output message prints out : b'This is the message'

I would prefer to have the output print : This is the message

Comment: You should make yourself familiar with the basic Python data types, especially `bytes`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html